# InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters

Tags: tensorflow

I am following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@yannicksergeobam/plant-disease-classification-with-tensorflow-2-0-268fe7f72c2a 
When I run this part of code on colab:

```
feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE,
                                   input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE+(3,),
                                   output_shape=[FV_SIZE])
do_fine_tuning = False #@param {type:"boolean"}
 if do_fine_tuning:
    feature_extractor.trainable = True
    # unfreeze some layers of base network for fine-tuning
    for layer in feature_extractor.layers[-30:]:
       layer.trainable =True

  else:
    feature_extractor.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    feature_extractor,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_generator.num_classes, activation='softmax',
                           kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))
])
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidURL                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-16-7f860a0e8414> in <module>()
      1 feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE,
      2                                    input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE+(3,),
----> 3                                    output_shape=[FV_SIZE])
      4 do_fine_tuning = True #@param {type:"boolean"}
      5 if do_fine_tuning:

14 frames

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in putrequest(self, method, url, skip_host, skip_accept_encoding)
   1125         match = _contains_disallowed_url_pchar_re.search(url)
   1126         if match:
-> 1127             raise InvalidURL(f"URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "
   1128                              f"(found at least {match.group()!r})")
   1129         request = '%s %s %s' % (method, url, self._http_vsn_str)

InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/google/tf2- preview/inception_v3/feature_vector/2?tf-hub-format=compressed' (found at least ' ')
```

Unfortunately I don't find something on google that could help me..and from the little python I know, I can't find the error...Can you help?

Comment: It maybe right a problem with the space between `tf2-` and `preview`. Try removing that so the line looks like: `MODULE_HANDLE ="https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/{}/feature_vector/2".format(handle_base)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
    pixels = 299
    FV_SIZE = 2048
    MODULE_HANDLE = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2- 
    preview/inception_v3/feature_vector/4"
    IMAGE_SIZE = (pixels, pixels)
    BATCH_SIZE = 64
```

Comment: Why? How does this solve it? Use this instead of what part of the provided code?

Answer (score 1):

In the MODULE_HANDLE variable you have space in its value:

"https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2- preview/inception_v3/feature_vector/4"

the space is between "tf2-" and "preview". you just need to remove the space.

This error is happening because urllib does not like white spaces in the url.

Comment: how do we remove spaces in the url, if any? not manually though. is there a way?